# Drawing graph in android

Tags: android, html

Can I draw a live graph using html or html5 and display it in android activity using webview or something else?? 
If it is possible then please suggest me how to deal with it.
Any tutorial will be the best practice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can opt for using a library like [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/). You can also do [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) drawing in android. Additionally you can do canvas drawing in HTML and show it in webview as you mentioned.

It all depends on what level of complexity are you willing to take and also what is really required. If you need to show a simple graph you can always use a custom class and use onDraw method to do canvas drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the
[link](http://www.highcharts.com/)
Hope it helps you 
[link2](http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-charts-and-graphs/)

However, please note that you can do even offline charts and also note that this is not done using HTML5.
For creating charts using HTML see this [tutorial](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-charts-the-html5-and-javascript-way/).

```
GraphView graphView = new GraphView(
  this 
  , new GraphViewData[] {
    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
    , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(2.5, 3.0d) // another frequency
    , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
    , new GraphViewData(5, 3.0d)
  } 
  , "GraphViewDemo" 
  , null 
  , null 
);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
layout.addView(graphView);
```